# How to create double nested fields where one field value can be overriden by another field value in Solr?

Tags: mysql, solr, solr4

I hope someone could help me in trying to flatten some tables for Solr with MySQL backend.

Here is the ERD: [ERD for products](http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/249/ja0h.png)

I have a product table that is linked to a content table and a market_content table for overriding content. Content in the sense of textual content. The product table references the content table by a foreign key to 'content.id' and the 'content.default_content' field shows the content related to the 'content.id'. The content can be overridden by the table market_content. If there is a corresponding id in the 'market_content.id' field that matches a record in 'content.id' then I want it to get content from the 'market_content.content' field instead of using 'content.default_content'.

Content either from 'content.default_content' or 'market_content.content' is text such as “shampoo”, “shampoo with conditioner”.

I am having trouble trying to get the structure to be as below on returning results from Solr as well as making sure that if there is an id in the market_content table that corresponds to an id in the content table, that Solr returns the overriding content from the market_content table 'market.content.content' field.

What I would like is for the results to be structured like this:

```
ProductId:1 
Market: 
GB: 
Content_id_description: shampoo 
US:  
Content_id_description: shampoo 
EU: 
Content_id_description: Shampoo with conditioner



ProductId:2 
Market: 
GB: 
Content_id_description: shampoo 
US: 
Content_id_description: shampoo 
EU: 
Content_id_description: shampoo
```

Product1; Market; EU; Content_id_description (content coming from the content table):  was overridden to say “Shampoo with conditioner”.

Is there anyway to get Solr to output in this structure and how would I go about flattening the ERD shown above to get the best optimised search on Solr?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end what I decided to do is create a separate table immitating a flat table structure with no relationships or normalisation and then after every insert into the normalised tables I would trigger off an event to populate this flat table structured table. Then what I did is configured Solr to use this flat table structure for searching

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion you don't need two tables for content. You can simplify the ERD as in the following [link](http://goo.gl/VB5A4k). In this you can have a default market with default code, which can be used for products which doesn't have market related description.

### For example

```
     product 
     id                code
     ---               -----
     1                 a13d4
     2                 b453d


     market
     id                code
     ---               -----
     0                 default
     1                 EU
     2                 GB
     3                 USA


     market_product_details
     product_id        market_id              description
     ----------        ---------              -----------
     1                 0                      Shampoo
     1                 1                      Shampoo
     1                 2                      Shampoo
     1                 3                      Shampoo with Conditioner
     2                 0                      Perfume
```

So, above market_id 0 is the default name for the product.

As for as querying concerned, since the table structure is simplified you can have query for solr like following:
`select mp.product_id, mp.market_id, ma.code, mp.description from market_product_details mp, market ma where mp.market_id=ma.market`

Comment: Thanks @learningloop. I like how there is a default field to carry non-overriden content though I am not sure if I can change the structure of the tables shown in my question as the db is handled by a third party.